# I accidentally corrupted a plist file belonging to the speech synthesis server, how do I fix it?

Tags: macos, applescript, system-preferences, text-to-speech

I was trying to write an AppleScript that would recognize the language of a selected text, and then set the speech synthesis voice accordingly and then let my Mac speak the text out loud.

This is how far I got:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set txt to (quoted form of (input as string))

    set resp to do shell script "curl -s https://ws.detectlanguage.com/0.2/detect -H 'Authorization: Bearer <my api key>'  -d q=" & txt & " | /usr/local/bin/jq '.data.detections[0].language'"

    set isDutch to resp is equal to "\"nl\""

    if isDutch then
        do shell script "
            defaults write com.apple.speech.voice.prefs SelectedVoiceID 5190
            defaults write com.apple.speech.voice.prefs SelectedVoiceName 'Pieter Siri'
        "
    else
        do shell script "
            defaults write com.apple.speech.voice.prefs SelectedVoiceID 101
            defaults write com.apple.speech.voice.prefs SelectedVoiceName 'Nora Siri'
        "
    end if

    do shell script "
        killall SpeechSynthesisServer
        pkill com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd
    "

    -- and then here I was gonna try and see if I could
    -- press option+esc to trigger my Mac's native text to speech feature.

    return input
end run
```

I thought I had figured out how to correctly set those settings, but apparently I was mistaken, because now text to speech doesn't work anymore and when I try to open it in System Preferences I see this:

[image: error in system preferences]

Comment: Quick fix for anything like this is to run an OS install from the Recovery Partition. I it will just overlay a fresh OS, without touching anything else.

Comment: Is there a chance it would mess with everything I've installed with Homebrew?

Comment: It shouldn't, but I couldn't say for certain; I've no real experience with Homebrew. Your alternative would be to recover the broken file via Time Machine.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the solution, which I learned from a user on reddit, was to delete my `com.apple.speech.voice.prefs.plist` file. It reset all my voice related settings, but that's better than a full reinstall.